# Multi layer borders for a box in CSS3

Tags: css, border

I'm looking for a proper way to have an effect highlighted in below picture at
the bottom of my box in CSS3.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Getting this effect with shadow will have the problem that the border-radius will decrease if you lower the size of the shadow. Can be solved, but it's quite convoluted.

Your best bet would be to use pseudo elements for this

```css
.test  {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    border: solid 1px green;
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: white;
}

.test:after, .test:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    border: inherit;
    border-radius: inherit;
    background-color: white;
    height: 50px;
}

.test:after {
    left: 6px;
    right: 6px;
    bottom: -6px;
    z-index: -1;
}
.test:before {
    left: 14px;
    right: 14px;
    bottom: -12px;
    z-index: -2;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have tried box-shadow? You could use box-shadows multiple times and control their positions. for example :

```
box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #color of your choice, (comma for another shadow) 2px 2px 2px #color of your choice, (and on as much as you want);
```

you can add another value like `1px 1px 1px 1px black` . the fourth represents the size of the shadow.
I hope this helps or if you could be more specific :)

Comment: can you provide a working example?